# How to concat compiled SASS and combined CSS using Laravel Mix?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

In my Laravel project I use both SASS and CSS: SASS used for dependencies (fontawesome, Bootstrap) - via NPM and plain CSS across deep folder structure (BEM). I want to concatenate all CSS, compile SASS and concatenate it all in a single .css file. Same with JS: plain JS files in my BEM structure need to combine with single `app.js` file which needs to be processed by Webpack. I tried this:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js')
    .scripts('resources/assets/blocks/**/*.js')
    .version('public/js/app.js');

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss')
    .styles('resources/assets/blocks/**/*.css')
    .version('public/css/app.css');
```

But it doesn't work - only manifest file is created:

```
{
  "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
  "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css",
  "/mix.js": "/mix.js"
}
```

Comment: what if you change all your .css files to .scss (with a script) - Sass will then be able to compile them

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').styles([
    'node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css',
    'public/css/app.css'
],'public/css/app.css');
```