# Laravel Mix Not Combining Styles

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

This is my first experience with Laravel Mix, NodeJS and NPM. I've attempted to follow the documentation from Laravel and believe I am doing it right, but who knows.

I'm attempting to combine several CSS files into one.

**webpack.mix.js**

```js
mix.combine([
    'resources/assets/css/components.css',
    'resources/assets/css/plugins.css',
    'resources/assets/css/layout.css',
    'resources/assets/css/default.css',    
    'resources/assets/css/custom.css'
], 'public/css/all.css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

**Run**

```
npm run dev
```

It appears to run fine, and outputs the following:

> DONE  Compiled successfully in 92ms
>   11:11:33 AM
>
> Built at: 11/23/2018 11:11:33 AM
>            Asset     Size  Chunks  Chunk Names /css/all.css  0 bytes    [emitted]   Entrypoint mix = mix.js

The file *all.css* is created where I expect it to be however it's empty. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be a known issue with webpack when using multiple css files https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/147

Answer (score 2):

I belive that [combine](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/concatenation-and-minification) only works to minify and combine js files. For css you have to use styles

```
 .styles(['inputA.css', 'inputB.css'], 'minified-output.css')
```

I have not found that in the docs, but I tried it and it works. Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48312321/2311074

Comment: Moved onto a later version of Laravel and its not an issue using combine. Hopefully this will help someone if they are using an older version